# How to access a signal of QGraphicsItem from scene subclass

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I need to read a signal emitted by a `QGraphicsItem` subclass, into a `QGraphicsScene` subclass.

Practical situation:

I have subclassed my `QGraphicsScene`, and many `QGraphicsItem` classes.

`MyScene` has a lot of properties reflecting changes of contained `QGraphicsItems` - including item size and position.

`MyTextItem` looks a little like this:

```
.h
class MyTextItem : public QGraphicsTextItem
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyTextItem();
    ~MyTextItem() {}
    QSizeF getItemSize() const { return m_size; }
    void setItemSize(const QSizeF s) { m_size = s; }
signals:
    void textItemHasChanged();
private slots:
    void updateItemOnContentsChanged();
private:
    void updateTextOnPropertyChanges();
    QSizeF m_size;
};

.cpp
MyTextItem::MyTextItem()
{
    setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextEditorInteraction);
    connect(document(), SIGNAL(contentsChanged()), this, SLOT(updateItemOnContentsChanged()));
}
void MyTextItem::updateItemOnContentsChanged()
{
    updateTextOnPropertyChanges();
    emit textItemHasChanged();
}
void MyTextItem::updateTextOnPropertyChanges()
{
    qDebug("updating things like size or position");
}
```

Testing the `MyTextItem` I can update its size and position when I type into the `QGraphicsTextItem`. (the only way to see it right now is to do another action that would force a refresh of properties - yet I know that works)

How do I propagate this at the scene class level ? (so I get instant updates)

I created a signal in my text item class `textItemHasChanged();`, but how can I connect it in the scene class ? (what would be the object ?)

The scene class... nothing special

```
class MyScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyScene (const qreal w = 300, const qreal h = 200, QObject* parent = 0);
    ~MyScene() {}
    // item add functions, item property functions, mouse overides
};

MyScene::MyScene(const qreal w, const qreal h, QObject *parent)
{
    setSceneRect(0, 0, w, h);
    connect(this, SIGNAL(selectionChanged()), this, SLOT(onSceneSelectionChanged()));
}
```

I would add a

```
    connect(???????, SIGNAL(textItemHasChanged()), this, SLOT(onSelectedItemsSizeChanged()));
```

But I don't know what the object would be...

How can I access the change in `MyTextItem` due to user typing text (`document().contentsChanged()`) from the scene class ?

Is the scene already aware of this signal ? (I mean, is it included in keyboard/mouse signals ?)

Or more general, how can I access a signal emitted by a `QGraphicsItem`, in the `QGraphicsScene` ?

I looked at `QGraphicsScene::changed()` - that signal is implemented from what I understand every time there is any sort of change...
Not sure how I can determine from there what has changed, and it may be very heavy-weight...
I added to `MyTextItem`: `setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsGeometryChanges);` but I don't see how this will help.
Writing the `MyTextItem::itemChange()` function ... I still don't see how to get the information from the scene class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the object would be the one which sent the signal, i.e. `MyTextItem` object.

And answering to your general question:
The way you can access to a signal emitted by a `QGraphicsItem`, in the `QGraphicsScene` is connecting the signal of the `QGraphicsItem` with a slot of the `QGraphicsScene`. Something like this:

```
connect(graphicsItemObject, SIGNAL(graphicsItemSignal()), graphicsSceneObject, SLOT(graphicsSceneSlot()));
```

I hope this can help you a little bit.

Comment: At scene creation, when I create the `connect`, there are no objects on the scene. There may or may not be an undefined number of `MyTextObject` on the scene. I don't know if it is a valid option to create a `connect` on each kind of `AddItem` or `Load` function... I have always seen these on constructors...  There may be hundreds or thousands of items being created and deleted, how does the 'connect` react to that ? Would I not get lots of errors after deleting items ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding you, but in order to have objects on the scene you need to create them.  I don't know how many `MyTextObject` you need, but you can create it as a pointer in the _private_ section of your scene class.

Comment: It seems that the `connect` pointers are seamlessly deleted when items are removed from scene, and I did not see an unusual load after creating `connect` pointers on item add or load, so it seems ok to create connects as needed.

Comment: Lol indeed to have objects on the scene I must create them. Also, to create objects (or load saved objects) I must have PUBLIC SLOTS in the PUBLIC SECTION of my scene class. And to connect some signals emitted by objects, I need to connect the signals to the objects. My confusion was based on the fact that generally I created the connections on constructor, and not constantly  adding and removing them. I expected for some mechanism to already be implemented in `scene()` that listens to items changes. But... that mechanism seems to be very complicated.